# How to check start and end of a message coming in stream in c#?

Tags: c#

I am receiving data from `streaming of bytes`.

**Code of TCPListerner :**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        TcpListener tcpListener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, 6054);

        tcpListener.Start();

        Console.WriteLine("Waiting for a client to connect...");

        //blocks until a client connects
        Socket socketForClient = tcpListener.AcceptSocket();

        Console.WriteLine("Client connected");

        //Read data sent from client
        NetworkStream networkStream = new NetworkStream(socketForClient);
        int bytesReceived, totalReceived = 0;

        string fileName = "testing.txt";

        byte[] receivedData = new byte[10000];
        do
        {
            bytesReceived = networkStream.Read
                (receivedData, 0, receivedData.Length);
            totalReceived += bytesReceived;
            Console.WriteLine("Total bytes read: " + totalReceived.ToString());
            if (!File.Exists(fileName))
            {
                using (File.Create(fileName)) { };
            }

            using (var stream = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Append))
            {
                stream.Write(receivedData, 0, bytesReceived);
            }
        }
        while (bytesReceived != 0);
        Console.WriteLine("Total bytes read: " + totalReceived.ToString());

        socketForClient.Close();
        Console.WriteLine("Client disconnected...");

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

I want to add functionality to process only that message which is coming from streaming starting with `<Product>` and want to check when the message ends. For end we can use `</Products>`.

How to perform this validation check in existing code, Any Idea ?

Comment: You'll have to come with some form of state machine, parsing the data as it is received. There's several options, like prepending a length-of-message section when sending (and parsing it when data comes in), or just parsing the data for "<product>" and "</product>" tags (again: parsing as data comes in), in either case you'll need to know in what state you're in when reading data, since not everything has to/will be received in one go. But on the whole, this is too broad to give a clear and concise answer.

Comment: I am receiving stream of bytes, I want to process that stream from only when I am sure that I have received ``<product>`` in it. There should be some way by which we can check it. Can you post your answer as per your understanding

Comment: Problem is: It's too involved to give a simple code example and/or answer. Data maybe coming in in one byte chunks. In its simplest form, based on your current code, you _could_ search the FileStream you append to for the requested begin and end tag. It's not something I would recommend (it may actually contain multiple occurences of the tags, for one thing). It won't be pretty, to say the least, but it will do the job.

Comment: @Gaurav123 Since you are writing the stream bytes to a file as and when you receive them, what if you read and check the file for the data you expect once after writing to it? Won't that reduce the complexity of interrupting the byte sequences?

Comment: @SivaGopal : I agree with you I was telling the same to my manager, but as per new requirement I will write the file only when I will be sure that message is starting with ``<Product>``. :) :)

Comment: @Gaurav123 In that case you may try reading from stream to a string and check for what you expect is existing. I think in that way you also don't need to write file every time you receive a byte, instead you can write that string at once after receiving all bytes to the file and I think it will save you multiple file writes which are expensive.